# Problem writing right to left in a docx file in java

Tags: java

I create a docx file in java in hebrew. I define the writing in this file from right to left. I have a problem:
when I write other characters that are not Hebrew letters they are written from left to right in the docx file that I create.
I am looking for a solution to always keep the continuity of writing from right to left regardless of the written character (Hebrew letter or other character)

my code very simplified is:

```
    String[] lines = { "שלו_ _רוך א_ד ש_יים", "של_ש אר_ע" };

    File fichier = new File("C:\\Users\\David\\Documents\\מבחנים" + "\\הסתרה" + ".docx");
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(fichier);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFRun run;
    XWPFParagraph par;

    par = doc.createParagraph();
    par.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    par.setSpacingBefore(0);
    par.setSpacingAfter(350);

    CTP ctp = par.getCTP();
    CTPPr ctppr = ctp.getPPr();
    if (ctppr == null) {
        ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
    }
    ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON);

    run = par.createRun();
    run.setFontSize(16);
    for (String line : lines) {
        for (String word : line.split("\\s+")) {
            run.setText(word);
            run.setText(" ");
        }
        run.addCarriageReturn();
    }

    try {
        doc.write(outStream);
        outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What code have you implemented thus far? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I couldn't find a duplication for Bidirectional Text with .docx. Despite the quality of the post, it's still a legitimate question to seek for answer about which API to use. This question has potential.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this on the table.

You might want to look into [Bidirectional Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/textlayoutbidirectionaltext.html) because Java Documentation has detailed information than I could assemble in this answer.

Microsoft also has documentation about [Bidirectional Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/user-interface/bidirectional-support) that could help with your implementation and has Hebrew examples as well.

If you're able to develop a proof of concept in a simple standalone JComponent, you might be able to do same in Microsoft.